# Is it possible selecting a non system Ruby from TideSDK when launching or bundling an application?

Tags: ruby, rvm, tidesdk, rvmrc

I'm testing the bundling of applications including Ruby scripts using TideSDK, via the TideSDK Developer app.
I have several Rubies installed on my system, using RVM, and was wondering if there is any way of specifying which one should be used using a .rvmrc file or something similar that the TideSDK ruby module can understand.

Thanks.

Comment: more details about how you use TideSDK and maybe some links could help

Comment: I was looking at the way TideSDK uses Ruby internally (or which possibilities did TideSDK offered regarding the integration with tools like RVM). meeech response explained my experience (no matter what you do, you can only use the system default Ruby). I guess changing this would require modifying the TideSDK Ruby module at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you planning to run your ruby scripts? via Ti.Process? Otherwise, the TideSDK ruby module is what it is - there's no different versions you can use with rvm (Afaik).

Update/Expanded: I should point out TideSDK bundles its own Ruby - its not using the system ruby. 
Otherwise, you can execute ruby scripts via Ti.Process (like any other script you would execute from the CLI). So, in your script, instead of `#!/usr/bin/ruby` you could do `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. Of course, this wouldn't be very portable if you relying on rvm on target systems, but if you are doing a limited ditrib to known targets (ie: internally where you know everyone has a system setup with rvm) you could probably get something working.